# Plotting nodes on a graph based on node-pair distances

Tags: graph

I was wondering if someone could help with the following problem.

I have a dozen nodes, each a different sized circle between 0 - 10. I have a distance for each node-pair (e.g. node A and B are 6 from each other, etc.)

Given this data, would it be possible to compute the position of each node on a grid?

The distance could be from the centre or the edge of a node.

Thanks.

Comment: I think there may be no unique solution to this, since topological transforms (ie reflection, rotation, and translation) are likely to give rise to multiple solutions. Do you require a unique solution, or any solution?

Comment: Hi @Chris - Any solution would be fine, as long as it can be plotted reasonably legibly. (2d plane preferred)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have a graph to look at, try building a [neato](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/neatoguide.pdf) file where you specify edge distance. Neato is a layout program that is part of the [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org) package.

This is quite easy. Your example above would look like this:

```
graph G {
   A -- B [len=6]
}
```